# Unity resets parameter value set with Editor script on play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I've set up a very simple Editor script in Unity 2020.2.1f1 that, upon pressing an Inspector button, should change the value of a specified parameter to a value set in the code.

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    DrawDefaultInspector();

    StateObject s = (StateObject)target;
    if (s.objID == 0)
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Object ID"))
        {
            GenerateID(s);
        }
    }
}

public void GenerateID(StateObject s)
{
    s.objID = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
}
```

This all works like it's supposed to. I press the button, the correct number appears in the field, and I'm happy. However, once I switch to Play mode, the value resets to the prefab default and remains that way even when I switch Play mode off.

Am I missing some ApplyChange function or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my eyes better than mixing in direct accesses from Editor scripts and then manually mark things dirty rather go through [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) and let the Inspector handle it all (also the marking dirty and saving changes, handle undo/redo etc)

```
SerializedProperty id;

private void OnEnable()
{
    id = serializedObject.FindProperty("objID");
}

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    DrawDefaultInspector();

    // Loads the actual values into the serialized properties
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.Update.html
    serializedObject.Update();

    if (id.intValue == 0)
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Object ID"))
        {
            id.intValue = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        }
    }

    // Writes back modified properties into the actual class
    // Handles all marking dirty, undo/redo, etc
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties.html
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had found something similar to this, but not as complete. I had tried it but it didn't work. Your example actually does work! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

(EDIT: This works, but isn't as good as the accepted answer.)

Well, yes, I am in fact missing some sort of ApplyChange function.

I don't know how I missed it, but I was looking for this:

```
EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
```

So, in my script, I would just edit the GenerateID function:

```
public void GenerateID(StateObject s)
{
    s.objID = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    EditorUtility.SetDirty(s);
}
```

And I am posting it here in case anyone runs into the same issue, that way they hopefully won't have to spend as much time looking for a solution before being reminded that SetDirty is a thing.